# getting a value from a map in java with index

Tags: java, collections

The item shown below is the result obtained from debugging a map

`{0={PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_AMT=200}}`

To store this value in a string I have used this code

```
String amountCheck=(String) productsFieldMap.get("PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_AMT");
```

However this does not seems to work. Can anyone suggest me a way to do this? 
The productsFieldMap represents the map where the values are stored.

Comment: What does "not seems to work" mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: I was expecting to get the value 200 in that string.

Comment: Please provide us the definition of the `productsFieldMap`

Comment: Is PRODUCT_TYPE a enum?

Comment: PRODUCT_TYPE is a table name in a database and PRODUCT_AMT is a field

Comment: You say this code does not seem to work. However you don't say what is returned by the code. Does it returns anything? Does it Return Null? Does it Crash?

Comment: Then it mostly means the key `"PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_AMT"` isn't found by the Map did you check how many values you have in the map? Did you put that value inside de map correctly?

Comment: The map was entered properly, but until i specified the index, the key was not recognized.

Comment: For future reference since you found your problem, the more information we get on your problem the easier it is to either try to replicate it or fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, you're looking for getting a `key` based on a `value`.

> You cannot get the `key` based on a value, as `get()` accepts a `key`, not a value.

If you want to do so, you need to iterate over the `HashMap` and get the matching value and return the key of it.

```
public static <T, E> T getKeyByValue(Map<T, E> map, E value) {
for (Entry<T, E> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (Objects.equals(value, entry.getValue())) {
        return entry.getKey();
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Getting a specific index removes that problem. That's the point which got me all confused

Answer (score 2):

Try this to find out what the map exactly contains:

```
for (Object key : productsFieldMap.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(key.toString() + ", " + productsFieldMap.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I missed something here and with this I was able to get desired output.

```
Map result = (Map) productsFieldMap.get(0);
String amountCheck = (String) result.get("PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_AMT");
```

Comment: I need to wait two days to do that.